# Motor power, torque and RPM importance (simulator steering wheel)

Tags: power, dc-motor, torque

I would like to build a DIY racing simulator steering wheel very similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp4gQ_euMsg) one.

My question is, how will the specifications of the motor used affect the experience at the wheel after the pulley system?

I understand torque is easy to manipulate with gears and pulleys, and that it will just change the turning force felt by the driver, but how will maximum power affect what the wheel can/cannot do, and is it related to the torque spec? Also, is RPM an important factor?

Comment: May I ask why this question was downvoted and voted to be closed? I don't mean to ask bad questions - I'd rather know the reason so I can correct my phrasing/ask it somewhere else next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power = torque x rpm. In a Permanent Magnet DC motor rpm is proportional to voltage and torque is proportional to current. Current is set by the torque load, while voltage is set by the supply but reduced by voltage drop across the motor's winding resistance (according to [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)). The result is performance curves that look like [this](https://www.pololu.com/picture/view/0J6476):-

[image]

Maximuum power output occurs at ~50% of no-load rpm and 50% of stall torque, at which point the motor is 50% efficient so it wastes as much power as it delivers to the load. At higher loading it wastes even more power and puts out less. Most motors are not designed to work in this area except at very low voltage, because otherwise they get too hot and burn out. This is why the right hand side of the graph shows dotted lines.

Your steering wheel simulator is effectively a [servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomechanism) which attempts to move the steering wheel to a position, but is torque limited so the operator can override the force it produces. The motor controller should adjust voltage to limit current and torque when the wheel is being moved by the operator, permitting full torque output when the wheel is held or moved against the servo motion.

For a given maximum motor power, the wheel can either move quickly with low holding torque, or slowly with high torque, depending on the gear ratio. Most motors are designed to run at thousands of rpm, so a relatively high gear ratio will be required to reduce the wheel speed, which also increases torque by the same proportion.

So you must decide what combination of maximum torque and speed you want, then choose a motor that has the characteristics you want. If the gear ratio is fixed then you must use a motor which runs at the required speed (divided by your gear ratio) on the supply voltage you are using *and* has the stall torque (multiplied by the gear ratio) that you want. This will also determine the maximum output power, which may be higher than the motor's rated power output (which depends on its ability to dissipate heat in its working environment).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got a lot more researching to do